# Prevent Auto Slide using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create product slider for devices - but the current jquery i am using is using auto slide - does anyone know how i can achieve this?

I have tried deleting auto: 3000, but i get a white box/image instead of the first image.

I need the first image to slide on then stop to allow people to choose to slide though.

```
var bullets = $('#thumbnails li.sliderindicator');
    var elem = document.getElementById('slider');
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
    startSlide: -1,
    auto: 3000,
    continuous: true,
    disableScroll: false,
    stopPropagation: false,  
    callback: function (pos) {
        var i = bullets.length;
        while (i--) {
            bullets[i].className = 'circle';
        }
        bullets[pos].className = 'on';

    }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try remove

```
 startSlide: -1,
 auto: 3000,
```

i think if  startSlide: -1 it will not display first image [look this link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EFHnd) .It work ok!